# Declare a function that accepts std:array in a header file

Tags: c++11, pass-by-value, stdarray

I am just playing around with std::array. Want to pass an array of integers to a function which can easily be done using

```
void arrayByValue(array<int, 5> arr);
```

The above can be invoked like

```
array<int, 5> aInt = {100,92,-1,122,112};  
arrayByValue(aInt);
```

This works perfectly fine as long as it is in same .cpp file. 
I am The issue is how to put this in a .h file, implement the method in .cpp file and then invoke it in another file assume main. I receive the error saying
**'array': undeclared identifier**
**type 'int' expected**

Please suggest what could be wrong. Please note this works perfect if I declare the function in the same file from where I am invoking it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add at the top of you .h file:

```
#include <array>
```

also use `std::array` - `using namespace std;` is a bad habit

Comment: I identified the issue. Just curious why using namespace std; is bad?

Comment: @SameerAhuja see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the inconvenience. I forgot to use
    using namespace std;
in the .h file. Using the above line or using std::array
 resolved the issue